# ML.Net - Cannot load a saved Model

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I want to reload a trained model with ML.Net in my app to don't have to re-train it.

Training and save it look ok. Create the zip file and fill it.

But when i'm trying to reload it from FileStream I get an `System.InvalidOperationException` with the message `Repository doesn't contain entry DataLoaderModel\Model.key`

My code is pretty similar to what I found on the [Machine Learning Examples](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/MulticlassClassification_HeartDisease/HeartDiseaseConsoleApp/Program.cs)

```
var p = @"C:\Users\{UserName}\Desktop\model.zip";
if (this._mlContext == null)
this._mlContext = new MLContext();

ITransformer model;
try
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(p))
    model = this._mlContext.Model.Load(stream);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw; // Invalid Operation Exception
}
```

Comment: You can open an issue in the ml.net github repo, and attach your model, if you have no problems with that. 
Since it is complaining about a missing file, `DataLoaderModel\Model.key`  if you look inside your model, is that file present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing to add the needed Nuget packages.
Make sure you add the following NuGet packages to your project:

```
Microsoft.ML.HalLearners
Microsoft.ML.LightGBM
```

Basically, you are getting that issue because the model you are trying to load contains a Custom Mapping Transformer which is implemented in one of those NuGet packages and accessed internally as a method extension. When we can't find that extension/contract we throw an exception during ModelLoadContext.LoadModel above saying "Can't find extension 'foo'". But there's an issue with that exception being "eaten" (our fault) and it is showing up a wrong exception.

This issue with "no clarity" with that exception will be fixed for ML.NET 0.11, probably.

But if you add those NuGet packages (or the NuGet packages needed, compare with your training model app), it should work.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: hi there, sorry to bring this up again. I'm having the same issue when using my custom .net standard library from a .net 4.6 web app (it works fine on a client .netcore app instead). I've added the 2 packages you suggested in your answer but it's still not happy. I'm also referencing all the packages that I reference explicitly in the model training app. Is there anything else I can check to understand what refs are still missing? Thanks!